# Where can I find a reference explaining how to take a C/C++ function header and define it with dllimport in C#?

Tags: c#, dllimport

I am using setupapi.dll to determine USB device connectivity.  It isn't working properly in 64 bit versions of windows (XP, Vista).  I suspect that the declarations are not quite correct, but am not sure how to verify.  MS doesn't seem to provide the dllimport information, but they do list all the function definitions.  Is there a resource I can use to convert between the function header and the dllimport declaration?

I've used pinvoke.net, but it looks like it doesn't account for 64 bit in the definitions provided.

Comment: pinvoke.net is wiki-based. When you find your answer, go back there and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net). It has a large set of Win32 APIs already translated to DllImport definitions (Including setupapi.dll).

Comment: I am suspect of some of the definitions there.  They work for 32 bit, but I don't think many of them take 64 bit into account.

Comment: Just a word of warning, I've found many incorrect definitions on pinvoke.net.

Answer (score 1):

The tool you're looking for is called C++/CLI. It was *built* to process those headers and generate interop code - no mucking around with P/Invoke.

Write a light-weight wrapper assembly in C++/CLI, and then use it from your C# code.

(Hard to provide a more specific answer, since you didn't really specify *how* it's not working properly...)